# How can I pass a powershell command in Ansible with parameters

Tags: powershell, installation, ansible, qualys, win-shell

I'm having trouble installing this particular agent in win servers through Ansible.

```yaml
- name: "Installing agent {{agent}} and webservices"
  register: executed_script
  win_shell: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c C:\SW\{{agent}}\QualysCloudAgent4.6.1.6\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe CustomerId='{{customer_id}}' ActivationId='{{activation_id}}' WebServiceUri="http://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/"}
```

This is the same command I use in a powershell script which works:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c .\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe CustomerId=$CId ActivationId=$AId WebServiceUri="http://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/"}
```

I've tried changing the places of the apostrophes, adding them, taking them away, hardcoding the `customer_id` and `activation_id`.

This is the command sent to us by the company to install it directly:

```
%BINARY_LOCATION%\QualysCloudAgent.exe CustomerId={xxxxxxxxxxxxx} ActivationId={xxxxxxxxxxxx} WebServiceUri= https://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/
```

Does anybody know how to sort this out?

I already tried changing the syntax in several different ways, I've tried different ways to run it in ansible, also tried with msiexec in the powershell script bit. The part I don't get is why does it work on the ps1 script and it won't work on ansible with the same script.
I have a few other agents that work properly with the same syntax.

Comment: You need the same account on both local and remote machine.  Best if the account is an Admin.  With admin you use a dollar sign instead of a colon in the path name so indicate the account is Admin.  So use : C$\SW\

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this but it did not work. I've tried what you sugested and quite a few other options and it's still making me crazy.

Comment: I just tried this: 

- name: Install Qualys Agent on the machine
  ansible.builtin.raw: Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c C:\\_IDTDeploy\\SW\\Qualys\\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe CustomerId="'{'{{customer_id}}'}'" ActivationId="'{'{{activation_id}}'}'" WebServiceUri="http://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/"}

Comment: Windows shell is going to run cmd.exe and not powershell.exe.  You need to run equivalent to : cmd.exe powershell.exe arguments

Comment: Hello @jdweng, thanks for your replies!
I already tried it as a CMD script, without the first bit which is from powershell
Tried this as well

  ansible.builtin.win_command:  
    cmd: C:\_IDTDeploy\SW\Qualys\QualysCloudAgent4.6.1.6\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe
    arguments:
    - CustomerId='{'{{customer_id}}'}' 
    - ActivationId='{'{{activation_id}}'}' 
    - WebServiceUri={{uripath}}

Still no luck, doesn't seem to want to install this thing through ansible.
I think it may be due to the parameters but the installers we have won't run if you don't use those parameters.

Comment: I would create a argument string so the curly brackets do not get misinterpreted : $arguments = "CustomerId={xxxxxxxxxxxxx} ActivationId={xxxxxxxxxxxx} WebServiceUri= https://qagpublic.qg2.apps.qualys.eu/CloudAgent/" Then use : C:_IDTDeploy\SW\Qualys\QualysCloudAgent4.6.1.6\QualysCloudAgent_4.6.1.6.exe $arguments.  Note that the path name is missing the backslash "c:\" So the executable is relative to where you are running the command when you do not have the backslash.